# numbers giving remainder 10 on dividing by 16

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determining the numbers that when divided by 16 gives remainder 10 ,  not getting how to approach this ?

Solution : Do we need to use a theorem ?

starting numbers are 10 ,26  , but as number gets bigger problem occurs

Comment: What problem occurs? You gave two such numbers. Can't you come up with more? Can't you find a rule to create more?

Comment: i can give more but is it good method to divide every number by 16 and then checking for remainder ?

Comment: sorry i was adding 10 instead of 16  dont now why :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a number, say $x$ divides $16$ and gives remainder of $10$, we can say $x=16k+10$, where $k$ can be any integer.  Using this, we can put any positive integer value or $0$ of $k$ into $16k+10$ to get a value of $x$.

Comment: sorry it was a silly doubt i was adding wrong thus not getting

Comment: @sumitgoyal please accept and upvote if you think it helps

Comment: dont worry you will get upvotes  :)